# How I can retrieve the JSON data in Android Studio using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my JSON from firebase

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "M3w9bHzu6fc7JTk7NAWkHxw80GO2" : {
      "matricula" : "a000000",
      "nombre" : "testing name"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve the data inside "matricula", I'm trying this way

```
public void retrieve(){

    this.ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
    ref.child("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("FB", (String) dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(uid).getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

But it keeps printing null pointer exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/.

Comment: can't find a correct example using java

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. Also: please post the actual code, instead of a picture of the code.

Comment: okay, good to know.